Swagger UI unable to be configured
I am trying to configure Swagger UI to my Springboot Project. But It is not working for some reason.
First, I added all the dependencies. Here is the build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:2.2.224'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.1.5"
    }
}

Then I added the SpringFoxConfig class:
package com.example.employeemanager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}

But after this, there is no Json at http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs and no UI at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/
I followed the steps on https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api.
I don't know what I am missing.

Did you read this part of your tutorial: It’s important to mention that the latest version of Swagger specification, now known as OpenAPI 3.0, is better supported by the Springdoc project and should be used for documenting Spring REST API. Moreover, Spring Boot 3 doesn’t support this library.

Start over by just using the gradle file generated with https://start.spring.io/

I followed this OpenAPI documentation: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation and it worked!
